# How to identify onclick on Usercontrol menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, user-controls

I have a usercontrol menu with sub items .how to find the onclick performed on menu item .
I want to show that selected menu item name in a label .
Am not getting how on click performed on menu items .

Answer (score 1):

Add an event Handler to the item in the User control as follows

```
// Add functionality to the menu items using the Click event. 
menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItem1_Click);
```

And Impplement **menuItem1_Click** method with the arguments.
Hope this will helpful to You.

Answer (score 1):

1-click the control 
go to property
click on the (lightening) symbol wich is for methods.
you find a set of possible actions, one of them is what you need i guess it is OnClick